# How can I use Bing Advanced Operators in my java code? (Specifically "inbody:" operator.)

Tags: java, api, search, operators, bing

I am using org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder.URIBuilder in my java code in order to use Bing Search News API. So I have this code:

```
URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder("https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/news/search");
builder.setParameter("q", keyword);
builder.setParameter("offset", "0");
builder.setParameter("mkt", language);
URI uri = builder.build();
```

"keyword" is any word or phrase which I want to search for.
I have read, that I can search for an exact phrase in Bing using inbody operator. Based on the information in this link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff795610.aspx

But I don't understand, how I should set it in my builder! I tried this:

```
builder.setParameter("inbody:", keyword);
```

But it didn't work. 
Generally, I don't know how to set advanced operators in my builder. Because they aren't parameters, and logically I can't set them with setParameter methode!

Comment: Did you try `builder.setParameter("q", "inbody:" + keyword);` ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I tried it right now. It doesn't work:
The method setParameter(String, String) in the type URIBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, String)

Comment: try copy-pasting my code - you've probably changed the `+` to `,`

Comment: Oops! Yes, thanks, you are right! I'd changed `+` to `,` !
Now, I don't get any error, and it runs. I also have to take care of the spaces between the words in my phrase. For example, if I want to search for this phrase: "brother and sister", then my keyword should look like this: `keyword = "brother+and+sister"`. Otherwise it doesn't work. But interestingly, when I use `+`, it searches for the exact phrase, even without `inbody:` operator.